# Remove spaces between delimiter and data

Tags: windows, unix, csv

I have a csv file like this :

```
xxxxx  xxxxx   ,xxxxx  ,  xxxxx
yyyyy yy   ,yy     ,  yyy
....
```

I would like to remove the spaces between delimiter and the end of the data before it to have this :

```
xxxxx  xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx
yyyyy yy,yy,  yyy
....
```

How can I do that in a simple way ? with a tool maybe ?

Thank you

Comment: notepad: search/replace `[space],` -> `,` repeatedly until nothing gets replaced.

Comment: nice, I will do that if there is no other solution ... thank you

Comment: In your example you have also removed the spaces between the delimiter and the beginning of the data. Is that what you want also or just a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, thank to Marc B, I have it but faster with notepad ++, ctrl + F, replace, (search Mode = regular expression).

```
Find : \s+,
replace : ,
```